# ¿Como arreglo el error Errorjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.DiverErrorjava.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Lo que pasa que estaba haciendo un programa en java POO, y conecte una base de datos con mysql, hasta el momento solo hice un botón el de insertar y cuando lo presiono me sale ese error.
Nunca eh conectado una base de datos, pero si agrege las librerias necesarias, la librerira mysqljdbc driver, por favor ayuda.

Ya eh intentado arreglarlo  y vi videos para nadie me puede ayudar, espero sea problema del boton, pero no dice nada de eso, como dije solo aparece cuando presiono el boton insertar y nadame marca error.

Mi código:

```
package Guillermito;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
        
public class Datos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/alumnos";
    public static final String usario = "root";
    public static final String contrasena = "";
    
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
        public Connection getConnection () {
            Connection conexion = null;
            try { 
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Diver");
                conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, usario, contrasena);
                
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.err.print("Error" + ex);   
            }
               return conexion; 
            }
        public void LimpiarCajas () {
            botonBuscar.setText(null); 
            cajaNombre.setText(null); 
            cajaDomicilio.setText(null); 
            cajaCelular.setText(null); 
            cajaCorreo.setText(null); 
            cajaNacimiento.setText(null); 
        }
      
    public Datos() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        botonBuscar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        name = new javax.swing.JButton();
        d = new javax.swing.JButton();
        hfdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jh = new javax.swing.JButton();
        kjyh = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        botonInsertar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        comboGenero = new javax.swing.JComboBox<String>();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        cajaNacimiento = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        cajaCorreo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        cajaCelular = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        cajaDomicilio = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        cajaNombre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        botonBuscar.setText("BUSCAR");

        jButton1.setText("CLAVE");

        name.setText("NOMBRE");

        d.setText("DOMICILIO");
        d.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                dActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        hfdd.setText("CELULAR");

        jh.setText("CORREO ELECTRONICO");

        kjyh.setText("FECHA DE NACIMIENTO");
        kjyh.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                kjyhActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setText("GENERO");
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        botonInsertar.setText("INSERTAR");
        botonInsertar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botonInsertarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton9.setText("LIMPIAR");

        jButton10.setText("ELIMINAR");

        jButton11.setText("MODIFICAR");

        comboGenero.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(botonInsertar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                                .addComponent(jButton11)
                                .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                                .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 79, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(11, 11, 11))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField8)
                                    .addComponent(botonBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                        .addGap(52, 52, 52))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(kjyh, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jh)
                            .addComponent(hfdd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(d)
                            .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(comboGenero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 377, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(cajaNombre)
                                .addComponent(cajaDomicilio)
                                .addComponent(cajaCelular)
                                .addComponent(cajaCorreo)
                                .addComponent(cajaNacimiento)))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(botonBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField7))
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addComponent(jTextField8)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(cajaNombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(cajaDomicilio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(d, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(cajaCelular, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(hfdd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jh, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(cajaCorreo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(kjyh, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(cajaNacimiento, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(comboGenero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(botonInsertar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void kjyhActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void dActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                 

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void botonInsertarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
       Connection conexion = null;
       try{
           conexion =getConnection ();
           ps = conexion.prepareStatement("INSERT into alumnos(Nombre,Domicilio, Celular, Correo_electronico, Fecha_nacimiento,Genero");
           ps.setString(1, cajaNombre.getText());
           ps.setString(2, cajaDomicilio.getText());
           ps.setString(3, cajaCelular.getText());
           ps.setString(4, cajaCorreo.getText());
           ps.setDate (5, Date.valueOf (cajaNacimiento.getText()));
           ps.setString(6, comboGenero.getSelectedItem().toString());
           
           
           int resultado = ps.executeUpdate ();
           if(resultado>0){
               
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro insertado correctamente");
               LimpiarCajas();
           }
           else{
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No se puede insertar el registro");
               LimpiarCajas();   
           }
           conexion.close();
       }catch(Exception ex){
           System.err.println("Error"+ex);{   
       }    
       }
       
    }                                             

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Datos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Datos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Datos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Datos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Datos().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton botonBuscar;
    private javax.swing.JButton botonInsertar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cajaCelular;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cajaCorreo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cajaDomicilio;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cajaNacimiento;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cajaNombre;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> comboGenero;
    private javax.swing.JButton d;
    private javax.swing.JButton hfdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jh;
    private javax.swing.JButton kjyh;
    private javax.swing.JButton name;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: y cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: **Errorjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.DiverErrorjava.lang.NullPointerException** ese mensaje sale en rojo en la parte de Output

Comment: y la traza completa sería? y quien es Guillermito?

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner "Driver" en lugar de "Diver" al crear la conexión?